# Grails Spring Security Core unable to log in

Tags: grails, spring-security

Installed spring-security-core 2.0-RC2 (with grails 2.3.6), ran the quick start but I'm not able to log in.  Each time I try, I get the 'Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.' error.

Done some research and I'm not double encoding the password or nor am I using salt (from what I can tell).  I've used earlier versions in other projects, so not sure what's going on.  I've also dropped the encodePassword() from the domain class and verified in the DB that it's what I expect it to be

Here's my User domain class:

```
class User {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
}
```

and my Bootstrap:

```
def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true) 
def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

def testUser = new User(username: 'me', password: 'me') 
testUser.save(flush: true)

UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
UserRole.create testUser, userRole, true
```

any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: would you please verify your bootstrapped data.  e.g. by adding ``failOnError: true`` to the save calls or by looking into the database (e.g. with the dbconsole of grails).  just to play it save.

Comment: I have verified that the save calls are working by checking the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine, but funny things can be happening under the hood. I wrote up a couple of blog posts to help diagnose issues like this. Check out http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029

Comment: Thanks Burt!  

Turns out the mongo plug in I was using was the root cause of the error.  Enabling the logging and using the event listener gave me the details needed to figure out the root cause.

Comment: Cool. If you're using Mongo you might want to also check out http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1992